# Override machine.config by web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I learn to work with the built-in profile provider of .Net, and have the following
problem:

I read that the machine.config-settings can be overridden by the web.config-settings
of a .Net-Application. The following settings in the machine.config-file are relevant
for me:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;
Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

<profile><providers><add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/></providers></profile>
```

These settings work to set up local profiles.
However, when I copy the settings into the web.config of my application and change the
machine.config settings, so that they don´t work any more, I get a configuration
error.
For example, I change the name of the provider in the machine.config to "Local".
This should be no problem, because the settings are overridden. However, when running
the application I get the error:

"The entry "AspNetSQLProvider has already been added" (my translation)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add a `<clear />` element as the first child of `<connectionStrings>`. It'll cause the configuration system to ignore all connection strings added in `machine.config` and use the new ones provided. You can also use `<remove>` element to remove a single configuration item if you don't want to clear out the whole thing.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <clear />
   <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

The same idea applies to `<providers>` sections as well.