# Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server error, but I'm not using MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to launch an ASP.NET MVC4 application in debug mode using Visual Studio 2012 (F5) but for some strange reason I'm getting an error that is saying it's trying to connect to a MySQL database. My application is using SQL Server. What's strange is that this MySQL provider is defined in the machine.config file of my dev machine. I tried searching the code of the app to see any reference to MySQL by no success. I found lots of questions in SO concerning this error but all of them are actually using My SQL...I'm not. Maybe the app is using it but how else can I find the proof?

```
Parser Error Message: Host 'fe80::401c:8841:1e03:2ea3%2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Source Error: 


Line 284:    <siteMap>
Line 285:      <providers>
Line 286:        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
Line 287:      </providers>
Line 288:    </siteMap>

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 286
```

Comment: Why do you have a MySQL provider in machine.config? You should not have that.

Comment: Well actually it looks like you are. So maybe you need to amend this so it talks to SQLServer

Comment: Ignore the "machine.config" file. What's in the "web.config" file?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: No, don't ignore machine.config.  That's where the problem is.

Comment: @SLaks It seems a bit strange that the OP is trying to use SQL Server yet the provider in machine.config is "MySqlSiteMapProvider". Wouldn't that mean that there is something missing in web.config along the lines of [Override machine.config by web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2201249/1115360), but for `siteMap` instead of `connectionStrings`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Yes; that's exactly what's going on.